# Docker meaase saying "another repo already pulling"

Tags: docker

I ran the following command in docker:

```
sudo docker run --name my_mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mysql
```

When i actually wanted to run the following:

```
sudo docker run --name my_mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword --volumes-from mydatastore -d mysql
```

Now after i ran the command(the 1st command) , the only way i could stop it was to close the terminal, soi closed it and then opened the terminal again and ran the second command, I.E.

```
sudo docker run --name my_mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword --volumes-from mydatastore -d mysql
```

I get the following message:

"another repository already pulling"(or something similar to this error message ... i just messed up all my docker commands and now i can't seem to re-create this error) , How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Either wait, or restart the docker daemon (probably `service docker restart`).

Comment: i actually ended up stopping all the containers and removing them indivisualling and restarting my excercise !

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't actually fix the problem - it just went away after the daemon finished or gave-up downloading the image - in effect you took the "wait" option.